# Which member of the crew is responsible to fill in the continuity sheet?

Tags: production, shooting

On a micro-budget production, considering the lack of a large crew with highly specialized jobs/titles, which of a maximum of three potential crew members would be responsible for doing the continuity sheet?  Authoritative references would be wonderful.